# Versioning AMQP Messages

Tags: versioning, amqp

Are there any established best practices around using versioned messages with AMQP?

Assuming I'm doing semantic versioning of my message schemas, I'd like to support the current major version of the message along with one previous major version.  Is this a realistic expectation?

What are the pros and cons to the different options for handling versioned messages? I've seen a versioned routing key and a version message header as possible solutions.

How do I determine which version of a message to send for a particular consumer?  Or do I send multiple versions and somehow correlate them so that in a send/reply scenario I'm only waiting for a single response.

What are some of the other concerns around building a system that supports versioned messages?